# Java- Integer in program not being updated

Tags: java

Recently, I've been assigned to do a file by my teacher to make a program that simulates a TV.

I am supposed to add volume when the raiseVolume method is called. However, upon calling it, it looks like volume is not being affected whatsoever.

I have no clue as to why this could be.

(myTv is the object of the constructor in Tv)
Here is the Code for the TV Driver Class-

```
System.out.println ("Crank it up!");        
    int oldVolume = myTv.getVolume();
    do {
        oldVolume = myTv.getVolume();
        myTv.raiseVolume();
    } while (myTv.getVolume() != oldVolume);
    System.out.println ("\t\tThe TV is " + myTv.getPower() +
                        " on channel " + myTv.getChannel() +
                        " at volume "  + myTv.getVolume());

    System.out.println ("That's a bit too loud");
    myTv.lowerVolume();
    myTv.lowerVolume();
```

and here is my code for the Tv Class-

```
private int volume = 0;
...
//Volume
public int getVolume(){
    return volume;
}
public void raiseVolume(){
    volume+=5;
}

public void lowerVolume(){
    volume-=1;

    if (volume > 0){
        volume = 0;
    }

}
```

If you need additional code, I will post it!
I've been called out for putting entire classes in here before, I don't wish to make the same error!

Comment: What makes you think the volume isn't getting affected?

Comment: This should work. The reason you shouldn't post entire classes is that good questions shouldn't include irrelevant code; however, it's still easier to answer a question with too much code than one with not enough. (Can you make a copy of your program, then remove all the irrelevant parts and put *that* in the question? That's the ideal situation)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The two values will never be equal, and your `while` loop just terminates. Print the volume before and after the call and you'll see that it changes (assuming you're using the code you've posted)

```
System.out.printf("oldVolume = %d%n", myTv.getVolume());
myTv.raiseVolume();
System.out.printf("newVolume = %d%n", myTv.getVolume());
```

Also, your `lowerVolume` method always sets volume to `0` (if it's greater than zero). I think you mean less than

```
public void lowerVolume(){
    volume--; // <-- does - 1
    if (volume < 0){ // <-- less than
        volume = 0;
    }
}
```

It might be a good idea to add a max for raiseVolume(). Finally, I suggest you set the increment (and decrement) to be the same value (or pass that value in to the method); that is something like

```
private static final int MAX_VALUE = 100;
private static final int MIN_VALUE = 0;

public void lowerVolume(int change) {
    volume -= change;
    volume = Math.max(volume, MIN_VALUE);
}

public void raiseVolume(int change) {
    volume += change;
    volume = Math.min(volume, MAX_VALUE);
}
```

Or,

```
public void lowerVolume() {
    volume--;
    volume = Math.max(volume, MIN_VALUE);
}

public void raiseVolume() {
    volume++;
    volume = Math.min(volume, MAX_VALUE);
}
```

Comment: Oh boy. It just keeps adding 5. 
I believe I have a solution.

Comment: Probably a good to add a max for `raiseVolume()`. Finally, I suggest you set the increment (and decrement) to be the same value (or pass that value in to the method).

Comment: I did as you asked. However, it seems that the max for raiseVolume() does not work and that the volumes seem to be the same

Comment: @Kultid_Games Edited to provide a more complete example.

Answer (score 3):

Because when you call `lowerVolume` after `raiseVolume`:

```
public void lowerVolume(){
    volume-=1;

    if (volume > 0){
        volume = 0;
    }

}
```

it will always set the volume to 0, as `volume > 0` (at least 5) at that moment, you should change it to:

```
if (volume < 0){
    volume = 0;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

try something along the lines of a start volume of 0 so when you getVolume you can write in something like

```
if(tv.getvolume == 0){
    volume++
}
```